# Why an error when doing "pip3 cache purge"?

Tags: pip

I'm building a docker container.
Once all is done I want to clean the pip caches.
Yes, I know about `pip --no-cache-dir install` but in my case, because I'm testing, I want to use cache until the end.
So, when I did:

`pip cache purge`, I got this error:

`"An error occurred during configuration: option format: invalid choice: columns"`

Comment: I do see `/root/.cache/pip`. So I'm wondering is it because of `root` user? Is it a `pip` bug?

Comment: `columns` is a value for [`pip list --format`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/#cmdoption-format). Either you've put it into a wrong command option (see `pip.conf` config file) or your `pip` is quite old and need to be upgraded.

Comment: I'm using `pip 20.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)` (after `pip install -U pip`)